# How to render data equally into 3 column list using Twig?

Tags: twig

I have array contains cities and I would like to put them on the 3 column list. How can I render an array of cities spliting them equally into 3 column list?

My html list:

```
                    <div class="col-md-4">  
                        <ul>
                            <li class="city-item"><a href="#">City</a></li>
                            <li class="city-item"><a href="#">City</a></li>
                            <li class="city-item"><a href="#">City</a></li>
                            <li class="city-item"><a href="#">City</a></li>
                            ...
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">  
                        <ul>
                            <li class="city-item"><a href="#">City</a></li>
                            <li class="city-item"><a href="#">City</a></li>
                            <li class="city-item"><a href="#">City</a></li>
                            <li class="city-item"><a href="#">City</a></li>
                            ...
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">  
                        <ul>
                            <li class="city-item"><a href="#">City</a></li>
                            <li class="city-item"><a href="#">City</a></li>
                            <li class="city-item"><a href="#">City</a></li>
                            <li class="city-item"><a href="#">City</a></li>
                            <li class="city-item"><a href="#">City</a></li>
                            ...
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

I am expecting the data to appear in this order

```
city0   city3   city6
city1   city4   city7
city2   city5
```

What's the best approach to render data like it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Update 1*: I have created a Twig Fiddle to incorporate suggestions in the comments.
http://twigfiddle.com/0h54xy

*Update 2*: If you have a newer version of Twig, it might be better to use the [`batch`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/batch.html#batch) filter. See http://twigfiddle.com/0h54xy/5 for an example.

---

This is where the modulus operator `%` is very useful.

The `//` operator in Twig will divide a number and floor it, i.e. `20 // 3 == 2`

Note that Twig's `loop.index` is not zero-indexed, the first value is 1.

```
{% if cities|length  %}
    {% set citiesPerColumn = (cities|length / 3)|round(0, 'ceil') %}

    {% for city in cities %}

        {% if citiesPerColumn == 1 or loop.index % citiesPerColumn == 1 %}
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <ul>
        {% endif %}

                    <li class="city-item"><a href="#">{{ city }}</a></li>

        {% if loop.last or loop.index % citiesPerColumn == 0 %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I've edited my answer with a cleaner approach to rendering the markup

Comment: Why not batch from twig?

Comment: @dextervip you could but wouldn't that mean more logic in the views? Perhaps you could either create a Twig macro or create a new Twig function extension to batch the array for you, something like `{{ batch(cities, 3) }}`

Comment: great. I would add `loop.last` to make sure the last list/column is closed: `{% if loop.index % citiesPerColumn == 0 or loop.last %}`

Comment: I would use `{% set citiesPerColumn = ((cities | length / 3) | round(0, 'ceil')) %}` in case `cities|length` is a multiple of 3

Comment: Its much cleaner to let twig handle this. see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/batch.html

Comment: This is not a solution for all cases, for example, if you have 9 items, and want 4 columns. http://twigfiddle.com/0h54xy/6 Any suggestion?