# Divide a long list into columns with Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm still pretty new to Twig.
I'm trying to build a dropdown menu for a website. I have multiple items which need to be divided into columns. I know this question is asked a million times but I can't figure out how to do this with Twig. I want one large list divided in multiple ul's of 14 items.

So lets say I have this:

```
<ul class="menu">
 {% for category in shop.categories %}
   <li class="item">
      {{ category.title }}
       {% if category.subs %}
         <ul class="subnav">           
           {% for category in category.subs %}
             <li></li> //can be up to 40 items
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
          {% endif %}
      </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I can't use CSS3 columns since every list varies in length. So far as I know you can't tell in CSS that you want 14 items per list???

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849682/how-to-render-data-equally-into-3-column-list-using-twig) like so:

```
{% for category in shop.categories %}
  <li class="item">
     {{ category.title }}
        {% if category.subs | length %}
        {% set categoriesPerColumn = (category.subs | length // 3) + 1 %}
          <ul class="subnav">

           {% for category in category.subs %}

           {% if loop.index % categoriesPerColumn == 1 %}
            <li class="col-md-4">
              <ul>
            {% endif %}

             <li>{{ category.title }}</li>

            {% if loop.index % categoriesPerColumn == 0 or loop.last %}
           </ul>
          </li>
         {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
```

I'm ending up with a submenu divided into 3 columns. What I try to achieve is to divide to whole list into columns of 14 items. Depending on how long the list is will result in different amounts of columns. So I don't want to set an amount of columns.

What I'm I doing wrong? Or how can I achieve my question?

I've read about Twig's `batch` function but that don't give me the desired result.

**UPDATE1**
I added a div column just to show what I try to achieve. I know this isn't correct, but just to show!!

```
<ul class="nav">

    {% for category in shop.categories %}
     <li class="item{% if loop.last and theme.hide_brands_button %} last{% endif %}">
       <a class="itemLink" href="{{ category.url | url }}" title="{{ category.title }}">{{ category.title }}</a>

         {% if category.subs | length %}

          <ul class="subnav">
            {% for batch in category.subs | batch(14) %}
             <div class="column">
              {% for category in category.subs %}
                <li><a class="subitemLink" href="{{ category.url | url }}" title="{{ category.title }}">{{ category.title }}</a></li>
              {% endfor %}
             </div>
           {% endfor %}
          </ul>

        {% endif %}
      </li>
     {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This give me a result like:

```
<ul class="subnav">
    <div class="column">
        <li></li>
        //complete list
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <li></li>
        //complete list
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <li></li>
        //complete list
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <li></li>
        //complete list
    </div>
</ul>
```

Can anybody help me with this? If this can't be done is there a neat jQuery solutions?

Comment: What did you tried with `batch` and what you don't like in that solution ?

Comment: @AlexandruG. To be honoust I don't know how to incorporate that in this menu!

Comment: Can you post a snippet from that menu array ?

Comment: @AlexandruG. Ok what do you exactly mean? I'm a noob sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `category.subs` is a two-dimensional array and if that is the case, you need to make one more loop:

```
<ul class="menu">
{% for category in shop.categories %}
<li class="item">
    {{ category.title }}

    {% if category.subs | length %}
        {% for batch in category.subs|batch(14) %}
            <ul class="subnav">
            {% for category in batch %}
                <li>{{ category.title }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: @Meules You have a typo after `<div class="column">`. Change `{% for category in category.subs %}` with `{% for category in batch %}`